# FluentAssertions - Compare equivalency where properties have different names?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm using FluentAssertions to compare equivalency of objects after mapping:

```
x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(y);
```

It's not uncommon for x to have a property which is named slightly different to y, in which case it would be a great to be able to **tell** FluentAssertions that the values of these 2 properties should match. Ideally with something like:

```
(y => y.PropertyWithName, x.PropertyWithVerySimilarName)
```

I'm reading the docs, but I can't see a clear way to do this. Has anyone found a way? https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/

Comment: `x.PropertyWithVerySimilarName.Should().Be(y.PropertyName)`? I don't understand. Can you post a more concrete example or [mre]?

Comment: So suppose class X had a property "StudentCourseName", and class Y had a property "StudentCourseTitle", comparing equivalency of the two objects would fail since the properties have different names so FluentAssertions cannot automatically compare equivalency. Suppose I wanted to tell FluentAssertions that these properties should be check for equivalency, is there an in-built in way of doing that?

Comment: Well, first, if you have two objects that contain different properties, you've got two entirely different Data Types. Unless you make a custom equality comparer, they will never be considered equal. Second, nothing in Fluent Assertions, nor basically any other library, will do a "close enough" test of property names. Either they match exactly or they don't.

Comment: But it's very common to use FluentAssertions to compare two entirely different Data Types? The very first example here does this: https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/

Comment: Of course, thus we assumed there'd be an easy way for you to specify that specific comparison in the options.

Comment: Looks like this feature is arriving soon: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535

Comment: This feature is actively in development: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of `Tuple`s here.

Just pick up set of properties to be "equivalent by":

```
var actual = x
    .Select(item => (item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3))
    .ToArray();
var expected = y
    .Select(item => (item.Property1, item.SpecialProp, item.Prop3))
    .ToArray();
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Just remember that the order of properties in tuple matters.

Comment: Really nice solution :) Just keep in mind, that tuple could have 8 elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`WithMapping` exactly for that use case](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#comparing-members-with-different-names):

```cs
    [Test]
    public void ObjectGraphTest()
    {
        var eins = new MyClass { Apfel = 1 };
        var zwei = new MyClass2 { Apfelsaft = 1 };

        eins.Should().BeEquivalentTo(zwei, config => config.WithMapping<MyClass>(x => x.Apfelsaft, x => x.Apfel));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use this method

```
actual
     .Should()
     .Match<Candle>(options => options.SomeProperty.Equals(anotherProperty))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).